# How to know that the signed URL for s3 put-object request was used and file was uploaded completely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am developing a web application where the user uploads a file into s3 by

1. Requesting a signed URL for upload from AWS lambda function.
2. Using the signed URL to upload the file into the s3 bucket.

---

3. Saving the uploaded s3 file URL into the database.

For step three, I need to know whether the user has uploaded the file completely into the s3 bucket for that given signed URL so that I can store that URL in my MySQL database for that particular user.

Comment: Just send server a message after the upload is finished on the client side.

Comment: @jellycsc Is it okay to send 3 requests for uploading a single file? 1.request signed URL 2.Upload file 3.Send uploaded confirmation.  I am using AWS lambda functions for the backend. So I have to create another lambda for confirmation of the upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate the destination bucket with a S3 event. When the upload is finished you update the database with the URL.

There is two alternatives for that:

1. accept data for the file upload and save it on the database with status pending;
2. send back the signedUrl as response;
3. file is uploaded by frontend;
4. S3 triggers an event that is sent to Lambda Function
5. Update database with status uploaded and the correct url

If you don't need to save any metadata, only the url, you can answer with the signedUrl and do not update the database at the first step.

You can find more information about this strategy in the [S3 official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).